# Best practice to isolate data access layer in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, dao

So, I have Ruby on Rails application. Blank for now. And let me say right from the beginning that most of my experience is from Java, so I might be thinking not the way RoR devs do. :-)

What I need to do is to create some Data Access Layer, say it will be access users, so let it be
UserDAO.rb which will be basically then using ActiveRecord *or* directly accessing the database *or* accessing *or* some key-value storage *or* anything else I can think of.

Technically, as we don't have interfaces in Ruby, I can make UserDAO.rb to "have" the implementation (basically, I am talking about composition), which may be anything we need, say UserDAOActiveRecord.rb or UserDAOMongo.rb or anything else like that. UserDAO.rb will basically call the methods of the implementation and that's it. Should be easy to switch between implementations.

While it does sound like a possible solution, I am looking forward to hear what are the best practices for this problem in the Ruby world. Thanks!

Comment: ActiveRecord abstracts the database layer for you. Switching from PostgreSQL to MySQL to MongoDB happens beneath your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to look for a Ruby Class other than ActiveRecord (which as pointed out is an Object Relational Mapper, so has no separate data access layer).

You might want to look at: https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel

You could create a class, `Person`, which contains methods which use an instance of Sequel to talk to the database.

This untested code demonstrates why this might not be a great idea:

```
class Person
  attr_reader :first_name, :last_name

  DataSource = Sequel.sqlite('my_app.db')[:people]

  def initialize(record)
    @first_name = record.first_name
    @last_name = record.last_name
  end

  # Find a record from the database and use it to initialize a new Person object 
  def self.find_by_id(id)
    self.new(Table.where(:id => id))
  end
end
```

Comment: To add to this it does seem that there is no 'go to' plugin for having separate data and business logic layers. I do think it is something that is missing in Ruby/Rails. By the way with Rails 3 it is much easier to use something other than ActiveRecord for your models.

Comment: There is now ROM (Ruby Object Mapper) https://rom-rb.org. For relational databases it uses the Sequel gem under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that ActiveRecord isn't only a way to access a database, it's also a pattern for how your data is integrated into your application: the idea that each model controls its own data and stores/retrieves/queries it as needed, with a model instance representing a database row.

Naturally, you don't have to use that pattern, but it's one of the cores of Rails, so by treating ActiveRecord as just another data access method to be abstracted, you're losing a lot of functionality.

Note also that ActiveRecord already abstracts out the database type by using a database adapter, so it's easy to drop in MySQL, Oracle, etc.  But it does assume a relational database.

However, to answer your question, it's not really necessary to wrap your data access implementation in another class just to ensure a consistent interface.  As you say, ruby doesn't have Java-type interfaces, but the ruby world also doesn't generally try to ensure that developers can only do legal things.  You can create a bunch of data access classes that offer the same set of methods, create unit tests to ensure that those methods are consistent (and to act as executable documentation of those methods), and then trust developers to make the correct calls against whichever implementation they pick.  It's a big cultural difference from the Java world, where everything is coded to interfaces and methods are final and objects are immutable.  It takes some getting used to.

Comment: Okay, I know about abstracting as for the DB/Relational access. But if I need to change it so it'll use some key-value storage with specific way of decrypting the value before it becomes an "object"

Comment: One of the nice things about ruby is how everything is modifiable.  The way active record works is that, if I ask for person.first_name, it treats "first_name" as a call to a method that doesn't exist, and in the Person classes `method_missing` class, it makes the call to the database.  So, you could override `method_missing` and do your own retrieval calls from there.  Similarly, you can retrieve from a cache at this point.

Comment: @JacobMattison i agree on your points. Nevertheless I think on very complex application  Activerecords (or any ORM) can and should be put in its own data access layer and only used within the data access layer to simplify the access and map the results via DTO's  (or directly) to the Business Layer that has no depencies to other layers or external orms etc (if you strictly follow DDD). With this cleaner separation you have the possibility to switch the orm whenever possible without breaking the business logic. Also not every layer needs to have a DB connection...

Answer (score 1):

Alex, I **strongly** suggest you to get the book Agile Web Devoplment With Rails (4th edition). Active Record implements the ... active record pattern, so the Class is the DAO (the class methods represent the dao), while the instance methods represents the object.

So for example you can have

```
person = Person.find(3)   //Person is the dao
person.name = 'mick'      //name = is the setter for he instance
person.save               // well.. saves the object
```

I've coded in Java for 10 years and just started with ruby..... and it's quite a change.

Comment: Okay, so say I need to change the way it works -- I want "Person" to have my implementation -- and might be not the SQL one, but something very different. How do I change it? Also, if I decide to cache some pieces, what's the best way of doing it? I want to isolate the controller as much as possible from this headache.